# Swift- Decode Dictionary in same order

Tags: ios, swift

```
    "quantityRemaining":{
         "stock":{
            "1000":5,
            "2000":4,
            "3000":9,
            "4000":15,
            "5000":12
         }
     }
```

I have a JSON which tells me the stock left in each store. The stock variable holds a dictionary with store number as key and quantity remaining as value, My requirement is to display this in the same order, however, when I use a dictionary to decode this, The order obviously gets jumbled. Is there a way to maintain the order and decode

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections. Write a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` function and map `stock` to an array of tuples which you can sort by the dictionary key.

Comment: Would you kindly provide us with the decoding part of your code?

Comment: Dictionary don't have order. When you want to display them, sort the values. Or use another structure.

Answer (score 0):

As we know dictionaries are not sorted nor can be so a work around would be converting it to array of tuples and use that instead.

Considering you have it decoded as `stock` you need to convert it to tuples array and sort that, and use it instead.

```
var tuplesArray: [(String,Int)] = []
stock.forEach { (key,value) in
 tuplesArray.append((key,value))
}
var sorted = tuplesArray.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
print(sorted) // [("1000", 5), ("2000", 4), ("3000", 9), ("4000", 15), ("5000", 12)]
```

Where `tuplesArray[0].0 // is the key`
And `tuplesArray[0].1 // is the value`

Comment: Problems in this solution:
1. Sets do not conform to Codable
2. The point is to save the manual sorting and use the exact sorting done in the JSON response